# Access denied on some files

Tags: php, drupal, permissions

I'm trying to set up drupal on my local machine but when I'm going to run the installation script I get access denied and I get error messages in my log files.

In php-fpm/www-error.log

```
[12-Jul-2018 09:05:10 UTC] PHP Warning:  Unknown: failed to open stream: Permission denied in Unknown on line 0
```

And in httpd/error.log

```
[Thu Jul 12 11:05:10.936497 2018] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 14538:tid 139710336833280] [client ::1:41360] AH01071: Got error 'Unable to open primary script: /var/www/html/install.php (Permission denied)\n'
```

I created test.php in the same directory and that file works fine. All files in have the permission 777.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change permissions of Folders to 755 and permissions of Files to 644

Comment: Tried it and it didn't work. As i expected since 777 includes bot 755 and 644 permissions.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this error on Fedora 29 by changing the SELinux context

```
[Wed Mar 27 13:40:29.145082 2019] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 5666:tid 140002260391680] [client 127.0.0.1:58332
AH01071: Got error 'Unable to open primary script: /var/www/html/wordpress/index.php (Permission denied)
```

While the ownership and permissions appear correct, `ls -z` shows the context types as:

`unconfined_u:object_r:default_t:s0`

To fix, the following steps can be done:

```
semanage fcontext -a -R -t httpd_sys_content_t /var/www/html/wordpress
```

The `-a` parameter means to add a record of the fcontext object type

The `-t` specifies the type, in this case: `httpd_sys_content_t`

The `-R` parameter means to apply the changes recursively

```
restorecon -v -R /var/www/html/wordpress
```

Comment: How dreadful that this last resort didn't help me. What's more, I don't know how to revert these changes now...

Comment: Was able to revert: `semanage fcontext -m -t user_home_t "/var/www/html/whatever(/.*)?" && restorecon -v -R /var/www/html/whatever`